# Is there Cache with Linq query support

Tags: .net, linq, caching

Is there Cache preferably a distributed cache with Linq query support?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any yet but Velocity will support Linq. I'm not sure if they are going to support it at ctp3 that launches any day now or at v1.

http://weblogs.asp.net/rchartier/archive/2009/03/13/microsoft-velocity-q-amp-a.aspx